# Hawking & Ellis: typo on page 16?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, vectors, terminology, linear-algebra

On [page 16](https://archive.org/details/largescalestruct0000hawk/page/16/mode/1up?view=theater) of *The Large Scale Structure of Space-Time* (1973) by Hawking and Ellis, they describe the basics of tangent spaces. This line appears near the top of the page:

> Thus the tangent vectors at $p$ form a vector space over $R^1$ spanned by the coordinate derivatives
> (∂/∂x<sup>j</sup>)|<sub>p</sub>...

Shouldn't it be $R^n$ instead of $R^1$?

Is it simply a typo?

Comment: A vector space over $R^1$ means a vector space over a real field, i.e.,  the components $V^j$ of a vector $V$ are all real numbers.

Comment: Interesting. I see others are confused by the lingo too: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4261541/

Comment: I could accept this as an answer, but it's a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not a typo. The entire phrase *“$V$ is a vector space over a field $\Bbb{F}$”* should be thought of as a whole; the precise definition is as a tuple of information $(V,+,\cdot,\Bbb{F})$, where $+:V\times V\to V$ and $\cdot:\Bbb{F}\times V\to V$ are given functions (called the “operations” of *vector addition* and *scalar multiplication* respectively) such that a list of 8 or so axioms are satisfied. See [What exactly is a "vector" in math (in terms of vector spaces)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4351469/568204) to get over the hurdle from the usual introductory definition of vectors (as pointy arrows with length and direction), into the more abstract and general treatment (take a look in page 1 of any proper linear algebra textbook, e.g Friedberg, Insel, Spence, for a more detailed description).

Next, completely separate from the definition of a vector space over a field, is the definition of *dimension of a vector space* (over a given field), $\dim_{\Bbb{F}}V$.

A-priori separate from this notion of dimension of vector space, is the notion of *dimension of a smooth manifold*.

What that little portion of Hawking and Ellis’ text is telling you is that if you consider a smooth $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ (the word “dimension” here being used in the sense of manifolds), and a point $p\in M$, then the set of tangent vectors, $T_pM$, actually forms a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$, and furthermore if you consider a coordinate chart $(U,x)$ around the point $p$, then the set of tangent vectors $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}(p)\right\}_{i=1}^n\subset T_pM$ forms a basis for $T_pM$. Therefore, $T_pM$, as a vector space has dimension $n$, which is also the same as the manifold’s dimension.

Comment: btw if you’re not comfortable with these basic definitions, then Hawking and Ellis isn’t really the right place to start. I would suggest first focusing on linear algebra and probably another text for the basics of differential geometry (or for instance watch atleast the [first few lectures](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLmsIjFudc1l2wDQ_ekx6iLtqcWJQQvOsw), say 1-5), then you can rapidly review Hawking and Ellis’ notation in chapter 2.